# Converting Floating to Integer

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define:

```
square :: Integer -> Integer 
square = round . (** 2)
```

and I am getting:

```
<interactive>:9:9: error:
    • No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of ‘round’
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘round’
      In the expression: round . (** 2)
      In an equation for ‘square’: square = round . (** 2)

<interactive>:9:18: error:
    • No instance for (Floating Integer)
        arising from an operator section
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(** 2)’
      In the expression: round . (** 2)
      In an equation for ‘square’: square = round . (** 2)
```

I am still new in this language and I seem to be unable to convert an instance of Floating to an Integer. Does anybody know how can I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell has multiple exponent functions with different types:

- [`(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-)
- [`(^^) :: (Fractional a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94--94-)
- [`(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--42-)

The one you are looking for is just `(^)`. With it, you don't even need `round`:

```
square :: Integer -> Integer 
square = (^ 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an appendix to Alec's answer, which is correct, to help you understand the error message.  The type of `(**)` is

```
(**) :: (Floating a) => a -> a -> a
```

So

```
(** 2) :: (Floating a) => a -> a
```

(because the literal `2` can be any numeric type we need).  But `a` is `Integer` because your function is declared to take an `Integer` as an input.  So now

```
(** 2) :: Integer -> Integer  --provided that there is a `Floating Integer` instance
```

This explains your second error, because there is no [`Floating`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating)`Integer` instance -- `Integer`s do not support floating point operations like `sin` (and exponentiating with an arbitrary real number).

Then you pass the output of this function, which is an `Integer`, along to `round` which has type

```
round :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

We know the input, `a`, is `Integer` because it's coming from `(** 2)` as we discussed, and the output `b` is also `Integer` because the output of your function is declared to be `Integer`.  So now you have

```
round :: Integer -> Integer  
    --provided there are `Integral Integer` and `RealFrac Integer` instaces
```

There is an [`Integral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral)`Integer` instance, so that is used, but there is no [`RealFrac`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac)`Integer` instance, and that explains your first error. `Integer`s do not support rational-like operations like extracting the numerator (though I suppose they could...).

Answer (score 1):

As an appendix to @luqui's answer, if you wanted to fix the error (rather than just follow @Alec's excellent solution), you could convert the `Integer` parameter to a `Floating` instance first:

```
square :: Integer -> Integer 
square = round . (** 2) . fromInteger
```

Comment: It is debatable whether luqui's answer could have been condensed to a comment on Alec's answer, but this certainly could have been a comment on luqui's answer.