# Haskell: Find the nth root of a float

Tags: haskell

Wondering if there's a way to compute the nth root of a float in Haskell.  I could try to write an algorithm but before I do, want to know if there's a module or canned function that I'm not finding.  I found this page:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-1.0.1.0/docs/Numeric-Units-Dimensional.html

which mentions an `nroot` function but can't tell how to get access to it.  It doesn't come in the standard library (when I try to run `nroot(3,27)` it tells me the function isn't in scope).  I tried importing Numeric.Units.Dimensional by entering `import Numeric.Units.Dimensional` but was told it couldn't find the module.  I may be misunderstanding how to load modules like this one.

Comment: `nroot n x = x ** (1 / n)`. Or, if you prefer: `nroot = flip (**) . recip`.

Comment: you can always use exponentiation with the reciprocal number - as `sqrt x = x^(1/2)`

Comment: damn you beat me @Alec - write that as an answer?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Beware of the three different exponentiation operators `**`, `^`, and `^^`!!

Comment: ah you are right - I was thinking in terms of mathematics and less "haskell"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the definition of an `n`th root is really just exponentiation by the reciprocal of `n`. With that in mind, you are probably just best served writing `27 ** (1 / 3)` or `27 ** (recip 3)`. If you really want:

```
nroot :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b -> b 
n `nroot` x = x ** (1 / fromIntegral n)
```

That said, beware of the [three exponentiation operators that exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843813/converting-floating-to-integer/40843896#40843896)! Only `**` works for you.

---

I should probably add that `nroot :: (KnownTypeInt n, Floating a) => Proxy n -> Quantity d a -> Quantity (Root d n) a` is certainly *not* what you want. Note in particular that the root your are taking has to be a compile-time type level number.

Comment: “Note that the definition of an `n`th root is really just exponentiation by the reciprocal of `n`”. Though this is _possible_, it's arguably not a very nice definition. In particular, it first requires you to define exponentiation with a rational number... but there's no direct way of doing this (without referring back to roots), you'd need to define it first for _real_ exponents by using an exponential/logarithm sandwich. No, mathematically, it actually makes sense to define ⁿ√y as the solution to y = xⁿ (which exists uniquely thanks to continuity and monotonicity).